# Can't make angular app run within meteor templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, iron-router, angular-meteor

Can't make angular app run within meteor templates

here is my index.html

```
<body>
</body>

<template name="myIndex">
    <section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppController as app">
        <div ng-include="'client/index.ng.html'"></div>
    </section>
</template>
```

and here is my index.js

```
MyIndexRouteController = PreloadController.extend({
    'preload': {
        'async': ['/js/xxx.js']
     },
});


Router.route('/', {
    template: 'myIndex',
    data: {
        env: 'someEnv',
        assets: ''
    },
    controller: MyIndexRouteController,

});
```

After router rules executes and template appeared in rendered HTML no Angular directives is started, nor `ng-app`, nor `ng-include`.

How this can be resolved?

Comment: where do you initialise your app `myApp`?

Comment: in `client/ngApp/app.js`

Comment: Can you create a basic jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap for manually start angular, after the meteor template is renderedю

Angular automatically starts when there ng-app directive, but in this case, the directive is the template for the of other template systems.

Comment: Sorry, that forgot to mention, but i try this approach before asking. Something wrong with iron-router i think

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the angular apps needs to be manually initialised after the template is added to the DOM.

Looking at the documentation for meteor-preloader, that may be achieved using the following snippet:

```
MyIndexRouteController = PreloadController.extend({
    'onAfterAsync' : function() {
        //angular.element(document).ready(function() {
          angular.module('myApp', []);
          angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
        //});
    },
    'preload': {
        'async': ['/js/xxx.js']
     },
});
```

Comment: Did you try that or just theoretically? I tried put no success (maybe I made some mistakes, that is why I wonder if you try)

Comment: @peka , I haven't tried,  it's hard to reproduce this without more of the code and environment setup for meteor